# why a³+b³+c³ is never 4 or 5 modulo 9 ? (all integers)

Tags: number-theory, integers

could somebody help and inform why this is the case?
Then I will have to understand of what form is a³+b³.
a³ according to Fermat is of the form 1 modulo 3 (if a is not divisible by 3).
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what a cube can be modulo $9$? You can just test it yourself!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  According to Euler's theorem (generalization of Fermat's), $a^6\equiv1\pmod9$ if $3\nmid a$

Comment: We can't drive there because we didn't put enough gas into the car.

Answer (score 0):

Because $n^3\equiv0$ or $\pm1\pmod 9$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an integer n ≡ 0,1,2,3....,8 (mod 9)

So $n^3$ ≡ $0^3$,$1^3$,$2^3$....,$8^3$ mod 9

Or $n^3$ ≡ 0,1,8,27,64,343,512 (mod 9)

Or $n^3$ ≡ 0,1,8 (mod 9)

If u know some basics in congruences , u will see that 8 (mod 9) can be written as (-1)  (mod 9)

So $n^3$ ≡ 0,1,-1 (mod 9)

Or $n^3$ ≡ 0, ±1 (mod 9)

So $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ ≡ 0 + 0 + 0 (mod 9) , or 0 + 1 + 0 (mod 9) , or 1 + 0 + 0 (mod 9) , or 1 + 0 + (-1) (mod 9) and so on .

Check Every case and you will find $n^3$ is never ≡ 4 or 5 (mod 9)

Comment: Thanks. My current thoughts: is there no X where it could be 4 or 5 modulo X ? (I am just starting thinking; and has to think more).